# Why does a Future complete before it´s handled by AsyncValue.guard() in Flutter (Riverpod)?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I´ve a Service that execute changes on a repository class, which writes the data to a database:

**Service Class**

```
class ListsService {
  ListsService(this.ref);
  final Ref ref;

  Future<void> addList(ListModel list) async {
    final repo = ref.read(ListsRepositoryProvider);
    final listsCount = await repo.countAll();

    /// returns as Future<ListModel>
    await repo.add(
      list.copyWith(
        isFavorite: listsCount == 0 ? true : false,
      ),
    );
  }
  ....
}

@riverpod
ListsService listsService(listsServiceRef ref) {
  return ListsService(ref);
}
```

And here is a controller class that consumes this service:

**Controller Class (uses Service)**

```
@riverpod
class ListsController extends _$ListsController {

  @override
  FutureOr<void> build() {}

  ListsService get listsService => ref.read(listsServiceProvider);

  Future<void> addList(ListModel list) async {
    state = const AsyncLoading();
    
    /// Here is the state error (Future completed) thrown
    state = await AsyncValue.guard<void>(() => listsService.addList(list));
  }

}
```

And here is my problem / question:
When the addList method (inside controller) calls "state = await AsyncValue.guard(() => listsService.addList(list));" the following exception is thrown:

**StateError (Bad state: Future already completed)**

**Where might the future be completed** before it´s passed to the AsyncValue.guard() callback?

**Update:**
I was able to reduce the issue as follows - the exception is still thrown in this function:

```
Future<void> addList(ListModel list) async {
    state = const AsyncLoading();

    // Exception thrown here: StateError (Bad state: Future already completed)
    state = await AsyncValue.guard<ListModel>(() async => Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => ListModel(title: 'Test')));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add async to future method even on the build method which can also be found in [your new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77949058/why-does-riverod-generator-not-generate-an-asyncnotifier-in-this-case).

```
@riverpod
class ListController extends _$ListController {
  @override
  FutureOr<List<ItemModel>> build() async {
    return await fetchItems();
  }

  Future<List<ItemModel> fetchItems() async {
    // Todo Something 
  }

  Future<void> addList(List<ItemModel> listItems) async {
    state = const AsyncValue.loading();

  

    state = await AsyncValue.guard(() async {
      // Add Future.delayed or Future.wait if you want

      return [...state, ...listItems];
    });
  }
}
```