# Why does Riverpod generator not generate an AsyncNotifier in this case?

Tags: flutter, riverpod, riverpod-generator

I want to generate an `AsyncNotifier` that takes one argument on build:

```
@riverpod
class ListController extends _$ListController {
  late ServiceOne _serviceOne;
  late ServiceTwo _serviceTwo;

  @override
  Future<List<ItemModel>> build(ListModel List) {
    _serviceOne = ref.read(serviceOneServiceProvider);
    _serviceTwo = ref.read(serviceTwoServiceProvider);
    return _fetchListItems(list);
  }

  /// A method I´d like to call
  Future<void> someMethod() async {
    // ... some state mutation operations here...
  }

  /// 
  Future<List<ItemModel> _fetchListItems(list) async {
    // ... fetch models here from e.g. an API
  }
}
```

The problem here is, that the generator creates a `ListControllerFamily` provider instead of an `AsyncNotifier`. **So I'm unable to access the methods like this**:

```
ref.read(listControllerProvider.notifier).someMethod();
```

The `.notifier` getter is not available. I´ve the exact same setup for another class but without parameters and there it works as expected.

Comment: Are you intentionally creating a family provider?  build() should have no params.

Comment: Yes, that was by intention - I simply had a blackout and forgot to pass the parameter value ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your provider is a [family provider](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/about_code_generation#passing-parameters-to-a-provider-family), because you provided at least one parameter to the `build` method:

```dart
Future<List<ItemModel>> build(ListModel List) {
```

To access the notifier of a family provider, you have to call it as a function, and provide the argument since the `list` parameter here is a required positional parameter:

```dart
ref.read(listControllerProvider(someList).notifier).someMethod();
```

See also:

- [Defining a Notifier](https://riverpod.dev/docs/essentials/side_effects#defining-a-notifier)
- [Passing parameters to a provider (family)](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/about_code_generation#passing-parameters-to-a-provider-family)

Answer (score 1):

Add async in your build method.

```
@riverpod
class ListController extends _$ListController {
  late ServiceOne _serviceOne;
  late ServiceTwo _serviceTwo;

  @override
  FutureOr<List<ItemModel>> build(ListModel List) async {
    _serviceOne = ref.read(serviceOneServiceProvider);
    _serviceTwo = ref.read(serviceTwoServiceProvider);
    return _fetchListItems(list);
  }

  /// A method I´d like to call
  Future<void> someMethod() async {
    // ... some state mutation operations here...
  }

  /// 
  Future<List<ItemModel> _fetchListItems(list) async {
    // ... fetch models here from e.g. an API
  }
}
```

Comment: Should not be necessary cause I'm not awaiting but returning a future directly

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the argument like this:

```
final ListModel model = ...;
ref.read(listControllerProvider(model).notifier).someMethod();
```

And every time you need to contact this provider, you will need to pass an argument.